# In the Lord's Vineyard what does the grafting teach (Jacob 5)?

Tags: exegesis, lds, book-of-mormon

[**Jacob 5** in the Book of Mormon](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/jacob/5?lang=eng) is a beautiful parable of Jesus Christ working in his Vineyard to save the children of God. It is prophetic in teaching how he works.

Here are some symbols involved:

- **Vineyard**: The world
- **Lord**: Jesus Christ
- **Tame olive tree**: House of Israel
- **Wild olive tree**: Gentiles
- **Branches**: Groups of people
- **Servant(s)**: Prophets and those that serve the Lord
- **Fruit**: Lives of people
- [More info here ...](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/manual/book-of-mormon-gospel-doctrine-teachers-manual/lesson-13?lang=eng)

**Jacob 5:55-56** teaches about some of the grafting the Lord does to save his vineyard after the fruits have become bad. We see later how effective this is. The grafting is part of how he saves the fruit.

> **Jacob 5:55-56**
>
> **55** And it came to pass that they took from the natural
>   tree which had become wild, and grafted in unto the natural trees,
>   which also had become wild.
>
> **56** And they also took of the natural trees which had become wild, and
>   grafted into their mother tree.

**What is happening here with the people symbolized and what does it teach?**

Answer (score 3):

It signifies the gathering of Israel. In grafting in both directions, the trees effectively become the same.

In more detail, one could interpret:

Grafting from the mother tree to the natural trees: Spreading the gospel to the dispersed tribes of Israel.

Grafting from the natural trees to the mother tree: Restoring the tribes, strengthening the House fo Israel.

Comment: Nice point! I like the idea of the gospel spreading across the earth and all peoples coming to know the Lord better.

Your point reminds me of `2 Nep 29: and the Nephites and the Jews shall have the words of the lost tribes of Israel; and the lost tribes of Israel shall have the words of the Nephites and the Jews.` and also `And when the two nations shall run together the testimony of the two nations shall run together also.`